# Git force ignored files, are they available at clean checkout/clone?

Tags: git, gitignore, git-commit

lets say I add one file to .gitignore and still commit it with -f (forced). Does someone else get it automatically when they do checkout/clone on their pc? Or since the file is ignored, its not downloaded?
Thanks

Comment: No, ignore only effects new files. If they where added before of if you force add them it will have no efect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file .gitignore, I think it is only used for change tracking. Once you pushed a file successfully to a remote branch, others can literally checkout/clone it.
But when they modify that file on their PCs, any changes of that file will not be detected by git. They must commit with -f to push the changes anyway.

Actually, I guess you can try your scenario on your PC with ease.

Comment: _"any changes of that file will not be detected by git"_ - this is just plain wrong. gitignore only works for untracked files.